# Detectar, en el destructor, si somos una instancia temporal

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy intentando detectar, **en el destructor**, si estoy en una instancia *temporal* o no.

Lo primero que intenté fue *cualificar* los destructores:

```
~S( ) & { ... }
~S( ) && { ... }
```

Con lo que obtuve un bonito mensaje de error:

> error: destructors may not be ref-qualified

A continuación, intenté esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  S( ) { algo( ); }
  S( const S& ) : S( ) { }
  S( S && ) { algo( ); }

  void realAlgo( bool tmp, bool dest ) const {
    cout << ( tmp ? "Temporal " : "No temporal " );
    cout << ( dest ? "destructor" : "constructor" ) << endl;
  }
  void algo( bool dest = false ) & {
    realAlgo( false, dest );
  }
  void algo( bool dest = false ) && {
    realAlgo( true, dest );
  }

  ~S( ) { algo( true ); }
};

int main( void ) {
  list< S > lista{ S( ), S( S( ) ) };

  cout << "Size: " << lista.size( ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Para mi sorpresa, la salida obtenida es:

> No temporal constructor
> No temporal constructor
> No temporal constructor
> No temporal constructor
> No temporal destructor
> No temporal destructor
> Size: 2
> No temporal destructor
> No temporal destructor

Es decir, **no se llama** a la función miembro `algo( ) &&`.

Tras pensarlo un poco, es un comportamiento lógico, dado que la decisión de llamar a una u otra versión de la función se realiza en tiempo de compilación. Al no poder cualificar los destructores, estos siempre llamaran a la versión `&` de la función.

Así pues, cambié de táctica. ¿ Porqué no usar un indicador, y establecerlo en el *move constructor* ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  bool temp;

  S( ) : temp( false ) { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
  S( const S& ) : S( ) { }
  S( S &&o ) : S( ) { o.temp = true; }

  ~S( ) {
    cout << "Destructor de " << ( temp ? "temporal" : "no temporal" ) << endl;
  }
};

int main( void ) {
  list< S > lista{ S( ), S( S( ) ) };

  cout << "Size: " << lista.size( ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

El resultado me volvió a sorprender:

> Constructor
> Constructor
> Constructor
> Constructor
> Destructor de no temporal
> Destructor de no temporal
> Size: 2
> Destructor de no temporal
> Destructor de no temporal

Así pues, la pregunta es:

#### ¿ Como detectar, en el destructor, si la instancia es o no temporal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de responder a la pregunta hay que aclarar una serie de conceptos.

Tu programa no va a hacer uso del operador `&&` **nunca** y la razón es que `S(S())` se beneficia de una característica llamada `copy elision`... es que los compiladores de hoy en día son muy listos los jodidos.

Para forzar una llamada a la sintaxis *move* tenemos que:

- Tener un objeto ya creado y hacer una construcción o asignación con `std::move`
- Que la construcción o asignación dependa del valor retornado por una función

Algo así:

```
S func()
{
  S s;
  return s;
}

int main() {
  list< S > lista{ func(),S(std::move(S())) };

  cout << "Size: " << lista.size( ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Pero claro, ahora el compilador se queja de que no puede aplicar la optimización de *copy elision*:

```
prog.cc:30:29: warning: moving a temporary object prevents copy elision [-Wpessimizing-move]
  list< S > lista{ func(),S(std::move(S())) };
                            ^
prog.cc:30:29: note: remove std::move call here
  list< S > lista{ func(),S(std::move(S())) };
                            ^~~~~~~~~~   ~
```

Podemos observar, sin embargo, que la llamada a `func()` no da error y sin embargo tampoco produce el resultado esperado... esto es porque aquí sí que está aplicando la ya tan famosa *copy elision*. Puede ser complicado forzar el uso de la sintaxis move en una única unidad de compilación.

Y bien, dicho esto ya podemos empezar a responder a la pregunta:

> ¿ Hay algún modo de detectar, dentro del destructor, si estamos sobre una instancia temporal ? Sin usar ninguna variable auxiliar.

La respuesta rápida es **NO**.

Lo único que sabe el destructor es que debe liberar recursos de una región de memoria dada.

---

**EDITO**

respondiendo a la pregunta planteada en la modificación:

> ¿ Como detectar, en el destructor, si la instancia es o no temporal ?

Tu código no es el más adecuado para probar la sintaxis *move*. El mecanismo de *copy elision* es, en este caso, prioritario al ser más óptimo.

Puedes ver tu ejemplo en funcionamiento con un código más sencillo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  bool temp;

  S( ) : temp( false ) { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
  S( const S& ) : S( ) {  }
  S( S &&o ) : S( ) { o.temp = true; }

  ~S( ) {
    cout << "Destructor de " << ( temp ? "temporal" : "no temporal" ) << endl;
  }

    S& operator=(S&& s) { s.temp = true; return *this; }
    S& operator=(S const&) { return *this; }
};

int main( void ) {

  S s;
  s = S();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edité mientras respondías, lo siento. ¿ Puedes echarle un ojo a la 2ª parte ? Usando una variable indicadora.

Comment: @Trauma ya te he respondido

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es posible poner ese "indicador" en el constructor, lo que sucede es que en el código de tu ejemplo no se está invocando el `move compy constructor` S(S&&).

Puedes agregar una línea adicional para que se vea:

```
lista.push_back(S{});
```