# Duda sobre como trabaja el return

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Tengo una duda, que llevo dando vueltas unos días, y no logro entender como trabaja o en que me estoy equivocando.

**Punto de partida:**

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente funcíon:

```
 ArrayWrapper f(ArrayWrapper arr){
      return arr
 }
```

Lo que hace mi compilador:

1- Al ser paso por valor llama al constructor copia, obtiene *arr*, y me devuelve un objeto temporal *arr*.

2- LLegamos al `return`, y como `arr` es temporal, y la función devuelve por valor, pues en este caso llama al constructor *move* y me devuelve mi objeto.

Ahora vienen mis dudas:

a) Si fuera mi `return`: `return ArrayWrapper(arr);`

- Comportamiento del compilador:

  LLama al constructor copia, obtiene `arr`, y vuelve a llamar al constructor copia. (`ArrayWrapper(arr)`, es temporal o eso pensaba).
- Lo que yo esperaba que al ser `arr` temporal, en `ArrayWrapper(arr)` se llamara al constructor *move* devolviendo un objeto temporal, y luego el `return` al tener que devolver una copia por valor, volviera a llamar al constructor *move*.

¿Por qué el compilador llama al constructor copia una vez que ya ha obtenido `arr`, y no llama a constructor *move*  dos veces, una para obtener el objeto temporal `ArrayWrapper(arr)` y la segunda para devolverlo en el `return`?

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Por qué el compilador llama al constructor copia una vez que ya ha obtenido arr, y no llama a constructor move dos veces, una para obtener el objeto temporal ArrayWrapper(arr) y la segunda para devolverlo en el return?

`arr` puede ser todo lo temporal que quieras... pero el constructor *move*, para ser llamado, necesita un [*R-value*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/914/463) y `arr` es un *L-value*.

Para forzar la llamada al constructor *move* tienes que convertir tu *L-value* en un *R-value* y para eso puedes usar `std::move`:

```
return ArrayWrapper(std::move(arr));
```

Ahora bien, en tu primera prueba:

```
return arr;
```

Has observado como el programa acaba llamando directamente al constructor *move* ¿Pero no habíamos dicho que `arr` es un *L-value*?

Efectivamente. `arr` sigue siendo un *L-value* pero aquí entran en juego otros factores:

- `arr` es una variable local de la función
- `arr` no es estática
- La instrucción en cuestion es un `return`

Cuando se cumplen estos requisitos (y existe el constructor *move*) entra en juego una optimización que pretende reducir la sobrecarga de las instrucciones `return`. En este caso se entiende que `arr` no va a seguir existiendo después del `return`, por lo que no hay ningún inconveniente en convertirlo de forma implícita en un *R-value* y poder llamar así al constructor *move*.

El caso que nos ha llevado a la pregunta:

```
return ArrayWrapper(arr);
```

No cumple estos requisitos porque antes del return se está creando un objeto adicional de tipo `ArrayWrapper`. Un código equivalente sería:

```
ArrayWrapper temp(arr);
return temp;
```

Luego, en el momento de crear `temp`, `arr` aun no ha llegado al final de su vida útil (y tampoco se encuentra afectado por el `return`), luego se invocará al constructor copia ya que aquí no existen optimizaciones.

Por otro lado ten en cuenta que en C++ hay otra optimización referente a los `return` que es la omisión de copia. Este tema ya se ha tratado en StackOverflow, por lo que para no repetirme te remito a esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101325/463).